# Modify Class Method Definition in TS or JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a class having structure like **:**

```
class A {
    constructor() {}
    myMethod() {
      console.log('in my method');
    }
}
```

I want to make a method that will accept `className` and `methodName` like **:**

```
modifyClassMethod(className, methodName)
```

This method should wrap the whole body of `methodName` specified into a callback during runtime.

So if I do,

```
modifyClassMethod(A, myMethod)
```

Now during runtime the body of `myMethod of` class A should get changed to

```
myMethod() {
   nr.recordMe('here', {
      console.log('in my method').
   })
}
```

Now when I will create a new object of `A` class, then I will get modified value of `myMethod`.

How can I achieve this in TS or JS ?.

Comment: Why you want to make to modify your method in that way?, you could extends your class and override your function

Comment: This looks kind of similar to mocking an implementation ... I think it's a valid practice in a testing environment. A good answer would involve altering the prototype of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help of **Decorator Design Pattern**. It's also called as wrapper. In Typescript you can do;

```
interface IClassInterface{
    myMethod():void
}

class classA implements IClassInterface{
    constructor() {}
    myMethod() {
      console.log('in my method');
    }
}

class AWrapper implements IClassInterface{
  constructor(private classA:IClassInterface){}
    myMethod(somestring?:string) {
      //this.classA.myMethod(); either do this, or do sth else
      console.log("wrapper works", somestring);
      this.classA.myMethod();
    }
}
```

and when using;

```
let aClass = new classA();
let IClassWrapper =  new AWrapper(aClass);
IClassWrapper.myMethod('here');
```